# Qt Segmentation Fault QTableWidget->SetItem(int,int,QTableWidgetItem)

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault, qt-creator, qtablewidget

**FIXED**

I'm writing a program that loads a file with 400 characters, and depending on the character changes the backgroundcolor of a tablecell on load.

This is how I create the QTableWidget:

```
QTableWidget* mapTableWidget = new QTableWidget(this);
mapTableWidget->setRowCount(20);
mapTableWidget->setColumnCount(20);
for (int i = 0; i<20; i++)
{
    mapTableWidget->setRowHeight(i,24);
    mapTableWidget->setColumnWidth(i,24);
}
mapTableWidget->setShowGrid(false);
mapTableWidget->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
mapTableWidget->setSortingEnabled(false);
```

I add the widget to the current layout with a simple:

```
QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout;
layout->setMargin(5);
layout->addWidget(mapTableWidget);
```

And this is where it goes wrong:

```
for (int k=0; k<20; k++)
{
    for(int l=0; l<20; l++)
    {
        QTableWidgetItem* tempitem = new QTableWidgetItem();
        tempitem->setBackgroundColor(mb->colorAt(l,k));
        mapTableWidget->setItem(k,l,tempitem);
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that I keep running into a segmentation fault at mapTableWidget->setItem(k,l,tempitem) when debugging, and the application crashes at that point too.

Does any one have any pointers (:]) to helping me out here?

PS:

This also happens when not using the color part, so commenting the setBackgroundColor line out (I know it's deprecated, but it worked on a different project) doesn't change anything.

**FIX**

The QTableWidget was allocated locally and was outside the scope where the additem had access to. Defining the table higher was the fix.

Answer (score 0):

This issue in my code was happened because of logic in cellChanged SLOT. I was trying to setText in QTableWidget that hasn't been actually created yet.

Answer (score -1):

```
QTableWidgetItem* tempitem = new QTableWidgetItem();
```

Try to add a parent to the object, 
for example:

```
QTableWidgetItem* tempitem = new QTableWidgetItem(mapTableWidget);
```

Comment: `QTableWidgetItem` is *not* based on `QObject`, and doesn't have a constructor with a 'parent'